# Python MySQL script slow, want some advice

Tags: python, mysql, performance, dns

I'm new to this site in posting, I've found a lot of answers here tho.

I'm not the best python nor mysql programmer, but I wanted to create a very simple script,
which put some info in a database where I can lookup and sort, what ever.

I'm trying to create something like a DNS request logger. 
A Windows 2003 (currently) server is logging all DNS requests to file.
Everyday I pull that (new) log file to a Ubuntu machine to process it into a MySQL db,
using sh and python.

Here is the part where I want some advice, the log file can grow quite big, around 70k lines,
with the code below this can take up to 20 minutes of processing easily. Is there any way to speed it up, (do i use terrible coding) or is it 'OK' as it is.

I've tried to make my sql commands as specific as possible, returning nothing more then needed,
only using commit once every 5000 iterations

Main outline:
Check if record exists in database, if not create, return ID. 
check if there is already a logged entry for that time (HH:MM, noticed multiple queries in almost same time), if not create entry, else add 1 to count.

that's it..

Thanks in advance who's willing to take a look.

Nick.

example entries:

```
20141204 23:00:50 172.000.000.000 A .www.google.nl
20141204 23:00:53 172.000.000.000 AAAA .www.google.nl
```

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os, sys
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb

# variables
dnslog = "dns-edited.log"
sqldb = None
sqlcur = None

def leesBestand(bestand):
    with open(bestand,"r") as entries:
        runcount = 0
        for entry in entries:
            # 0:<Datum> 1:<Tijd> 2:<IP Requester> 3:<Record Type> 4:<Domain name>
            words = entry.split()

            datum = setDatum(words[0])
            tijd = setTijd(words[1])

            domainId = checkEntry(words[4][1:],words[3])
            requestId = bestaadRequest(datum,tijd,words[2],domainId)

            if runcount > 5000 :
                dbCommit()
                runcount = 0
            runcount += 1

def dbExecute(sqlstring):
    try :
        global sqlcur
        sqlcur.execute(sqlstring)
    except MySQLdb.Error,e:
        global sqldb
        sqldb.rollback()
        print "[Error-Execute] : " + str(e)

def dbCommit():
    global sqldb
    try :
        print "[Debug] SQL Commit"
        sqldb.commit()
    except MySQLdb.Error,e:
        sqldb.rollback()
        print "[Error-Commit] : " + str(e)

def checkEntry(domain,domaintype):
    global sqlcur
    sqlstring = """SELECT dnslog_domain_id FROM dnslog_domains WHERE `dnslog_domain_name` = '%s' AND 
        `dnslog_domain_type` = '%s'""" % (domain,domaintype)
    dbExecute(sqlstring)

    row = sqlcur.fetchone() 
    if row :
        return row[0]
    else :
        sqlvalues = prepareInsertDomain(domain,domaintype)
        sqlinsert = """INSERT INTO dnslog_domains VALUES ('','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')
            """ % (sqlvalues[0],sqlvalues[1],sqlvalues[2],sqlvalues[3],sqlvalues[4],sqlvalues[5],sqlvalues[6],sqlvalues[7])
        dbExecute(sqlinsert)
        return sqlcur.lastrowid

def bestaadRequest(datum,tijd,requester,domainId):
    global sqlcur
    sqlstring = """SELECT dnslog_request_id, dnslog_request_count FROM dnslog_requests WHERE `dnslog_domain_id` = '%s' AND
        `dnslog_request_requester` = '%s' AND `dnslog_request_date` = '%s' AND `dnslog_request_time` = '%s' 
        """ % (domainId,requester,datum,tijd)
    dbExecute(sqlstring)

    row = sqlcur.fetchone() 
    if row :
        teller = int(row[1]) + 1
        sqlinsert = """UPDATE `dnslog_requests` SET `dnslog_request_count` = '%s' WHERE `dnslog_request_id` = '%s' """ % (teller, row[0])
        dbExecute(sqlinsert)
        return row[0]
    else :
        sqlinsert = """INSERT INTO dnslog_requests VALUES ('','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') """ % (domainId,requester,datum,tijd,"1")
        dbExecute(sqlinsert)
        return sqlcur.lastrowid

# Main starting function
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    dbConnect()

    leesBestand(dnslog)

    dbCommit()

    dbClose()
```

DB Layout

```
mysql> describe dnslog_requests;
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| dnslog_request_id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dnslog_domain_id         | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_request_requester | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_request_date      | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_request_time      | time        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_request_count     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe dnslog_domains;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| dnslog_domain_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dnslog_domain_name  | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_domain_type  | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_domain_part1 | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_domain_part2 | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_domain_part3 | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_domain_part4 | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_domain_part5 | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dnslog_domain_part6 | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to purge DNS log file more often ? How often is the log file purged at the moment

Comment: My intend was to do it once a day, when everyone is gone, since i stop the dns service nicely before moving the dnslog file, and then restart the service again.

Comment: So it grows to about 70k lines in one day ?

Comment: Yes thats correct :)
Maybe a peak day, others around 50/60k so far i can tell.

Comment: Inserting or updating line by line can be expensive. Instead, you can use batch insert. Maybe you can use staging tables to load raw data and   run a query to transform data to load actual table.

Comment: because i use 2 tables and use lookups to combine that did not seem to be entirely logical in my case/mind. 

maybe an idea to first run the file, prepare all insert queries for the domain table, executemany(). and then rerun the file for the request/count information, with again executemany().

or is that a wrong thought.

Answer (score 0):

Database operation will always take time , the best way to go about will be to keep a copy DNS request file on windows from which you can continue to process.

But , every 5-10 min send a commit request to ubuntu system in the back end.

Let me know , if I have misunderstood the problem.

Comment: its running once a day, copies the entire log file from windows to ubuntu, then do some magic to create a better readable file, then do python magics.

i know db actions take time, but thought maybe I really screwed up something in code :(

Answer (score 0):

i edited the code with some advise to do it other wise,
at this time the processing time is reduced to 3 minutes for a
small file and 10 minutes for a big file.

Not the best speeds tho, but better then before
(especially since the times increased with larger DB as seen in 1 mistake execute)

New script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import os, sys
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb

print "[Start program] " + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

dnslog = "dns-edited.log"
domainInsertValues = []
requestInsertValues = []
domainInsertQuery = """INSERT INTO dnslog_domains (dnslog_domain_name, dnslog_domain_type, dnslog_domain_part1, 
        dnslog_domain_part2, dnslog_domain_part3, dnslog_domain_part4, dnslog_domain_part5, 
        dnslog_domain_part6) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
requestInsertQuery = """INSERT INTO dnslog_requests (dnslog_domain_id, dnslog_request_requester, dnslog_request_date,
        dnslog_request_time, dnslog_request_count) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""

sqldb = None
sqlcur = None

def leesBestand(bestand,typeRun):
    with open(bestand,"r") as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            # 0:<Datum> 1:<Tijd> 2:<IP Requester> 3:<Record Type> 4:<Domain name>
            words = entry.split()
            datum = setDatum(words[0])
            tijd = setTijd(words[1])
            if typeRun == "domain" :
                checkEntry(words[4][1:],words[3])
            elif typeRun == "request" :
                domainId = checkDomainId(words[4][1:],words[3])
                bestaadRequest(datum,tijd,words[2],domainId)

def checkEntry(domain,domaintype):
    global sqlcur
    global domainInsertValues
    sqlstring = """SELECT dnslog_domain_id FROM dnslog_domains WHERE `dnslog_domain_name` = '%s' AND 
        `dnslog_domain_type` = '%s'""" % (domain,domaintype)
    dbExecute(sqlstring)
    row = sqlcur.fetchone() 
    if not row :
        add = False
        match1 = [s for s in domainInsertValues if domain in s]
        if not match1 :
            add = True
        else :
            match2 = [s for s in match1 if domaintype in s]
            if not match2 :
                add = True 
        if add:
            sqlvalues = prepareInsertDomain(domain,domaintype)
            sqlstring = (sqlvalues[0],sqlvalues[1],sqlvalues[2],sqlvalues[3],sqlvalues[4],sqlvalues[5],sqlvalues[6],sqlvalues[7])
            domainInsertValues.append(sqlstring)

def checkDomainId(domain,domaintype):
    global sqlcur
    sqlstring = """SELECT dnslog_domain_id FROM dnslog_domains WHERE `dnslog_domain_name` = '%s' AND 
        `dnslog_domain_type` = '%s'""" % (domain,domaintype)
    dbExecute(sqlstring)
    row = sqlcur.fetchone() 
    if not row :
        return 27885
    else :
        return row[0]

def bestaadRequest(datum,tijd,requester,domainId):
    global requestInsertValues

    sqldata = (int(domainId),requester,str(datum),tijd,1)
    match1 = [i for i,s in enumerate(requestInsertValues) if s[0] == int(domainId) and s[1] == requester and s[2] == str(datum) and s[3] == tijd]
    if not match1 : 
        requestInsertValues.append(sqldata)
    else :
        requestInsertValues[i] = (int(domainId),requester,str(datum),tijd, s[4] + 1)

# Main starting function
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    dbConnect()
    print "[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain " + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')    
    leesBestand(dnslog,"domain")
    print "[Start] Execute Many - Domain " + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    dbExecuteMany(domainInsertQuery,domainInsertValues)
    print "[Start] DB Commit " + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    dbCommit()
    print "[Start] Lees bestand - Request " + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    leesBestand(dnslog,"request")
    print "[Start] Execute Many - Request " + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    dbExecuteMany(requestInsertQuery,requestInsertValues)
    print "[Start] DB Commit " + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    dbCommit()
    dbClose()
    print "[Stop program] " + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Line count:

```
user@host:~/dnslog$ wc -l backups/*
   69913 backups/dns-2014-12-04.log
   57220 backups/dns-2014-12-05.log
   27883 backups/dns-2014-12-06.log
   30679 backups/dns-2014-12-07.log
   62546 backups/dns-2014-12-08.log
   50267 backups/dns-2014-12-09.log
   55166 backups/dns-2014-12-10.log
   57169 backups/dns-2014-12-11.log
   46335 backups/dns-2014-12-12.log
   18632 backups/dns-2014-12-13.log
   18655 backups/dns-2014-12-14.log
  494465 total
```

SQL Table's:

```
mysql> select count(dnslog_domain_id) from dnslog_domains;
+-------------------------+
| count(dnslog_domain_id) |
+-------------------------+
|                   35243 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select count(dnslog_request_id) from dnslog_requests;
+--------------------------+
| count(dnslog_request_id) |
+--------------------------+
|                   342005 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)

mysql> select sum(dnslog_request_count) from dnslog_requests;
+---------------------------+
| sum(dnslog_request_count) |
+---------------------------+
|                    494459 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

For those intrested in the execute times:

```
user@host:~/dnslog$ time ./script.py # 69913
[Start program] 14:13:45
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 14:13:45
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 14:15:45
[Start] DB Commit 14:15:46
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 14:15:46
[Start] Execute Many - Request 14:29:02
[Start] DB Commit 14:29:15
[Stop program] 14:29:15

real    14m37.079s
user    10m51.780s
sys     0m10.043s


user@host:~/dnslog$ time ./script.py # 57220
[Start program] 14:30:36
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 14:30:36
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 14:31:42
[Start] DB Commit 14:31:43
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 14:31:44
[Start] Execute Many - Request 14:59:18
[Start] DB Commit 14:59:28
[Stop program] 14:59:28

real    28m51.763s
user    7m41.154s
sys     0m8.981s


user@host:~/dnslog$ time ./script-v0.4.py # 27883
[Start program] 15:02:26
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 15:02:26
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 15:02:36
[Start] DB Commit 15:02:36
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 15:02:36
[Start] Execute Many - Request 15:04:17
[Start] DB Commit 15:04:19
[Stop program] 15:04:19

real    1m53.154s
user    1m35.524s
sys     0m2.226s


user@host:~/dnslog$ time ./script-v0.4.py # 30679
[Start program] 15:04:39
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 15:04:39
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 15:04:50
[Start] DB Commit 15:04:50
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 15:04:50
[Start] Execute Many - Request 15:06:42
[Start] DB Commit 15:06:45
[Stop program] 15:06:45

real    2m6.326s
user    1m45.733s
sys     0m2.472s


user@host:~/dnslog$ time ./script-v0.4.py # 62546
[Start program] 15:07:07
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 15:07:07
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 15:08:14
[Start] DB Commit 15:08:15
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 15:08:15
[Start] Execute Many - Request 15:16:28
[Start] DB Commit 15:16:38
[Stop program] 15:16:38

real    9m31.162s
user    7m7.657s
sys     0m5.947s


user@host:~/dnslog$ time ./script-v0.4.py # 50267
[Start program] 15:19:02
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 15:19:03
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 15:20:09
[Start] DB Commit 15:20:10
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 15:20:10
[Start] Execute Many - Request 15:27:48
[Start] DB Commit 15:27:57
[Stop program] 15:27:57

real    8m54.934s
user    5m54.422s
sys     0m5.197s


user@host:~/dnslog$ time ./script-v0.4.py # 55166
[Start program] 15:48:37
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 15:48:37
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 15:51:21
[Start] DB Commit 15:51:21
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 15:51:21
[Start] Execute Many - Request 16:01:14
[Start] DB Commit 16:01:24
[Stop program] 16:01:24

real    12m47.229s
user    7m12.642s
sys     0m6.413s


user@host:~/dnslog$ sudo ./script.sh # 57169 - Oops forgot copy correct script...
[sudo] password for monitor:
Start:  + 10:08:03
Sed / Grep / Awk magic:  + 10:08:09
[Start program] 10:08:10
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 10:08:10
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 10:10:53
[Start] DB Commit 10:10:55
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 10:10:55
[Start] Execute Many - Request 11:47:27
[Start] DB Commit 11:47:37
[Stop program] 11:47:37


user@host:~/dnslog$ cp script-v0.4.py script.py


user@host:~/dnslog$ sudo ./script.sh # 46335
[sudo] password for monitor:
Start:  + 11:52:31
Sed / Grep / Awk magic:  + 11:52:36
[Start program] 11:52:36
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 11:52:36
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 11:54:56
[Start] DB Commit 11:54:57
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 11:54:57
[Start] Execute Many - Request 12:02:39
[Start] DB Commit 12:02:47
[Stop program] 12:02:47


user@host:~/dnslog$ sudo ./script.sh # 18632
Start:  + 12:06:23
Sed / Grep / Awk magic:  + 12:06:28
[Start program] 12:06:28
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 12:06:28
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 12:06:40
[Start] DB Commit 12:06:40
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 12:06:41
[Start] Execute Many - Request 12:07:52
[Start] DB Commit 12:07:55
[Stop program] 12:07:55


user@host:~/dnslog$ sudo ./script.sh # 18655
Start:  + 12:15:36
Sed / Grep / Awk magic:  + 12:15:41
[Start program] 12:15:41
[Start] Lees Bestand - Domain 12:15:41
[Start] Execute Many - Domain 12:15:54
[Start] DB Commit 12:15:54
[Start] Lees bestand - Request 12:15:54
[Start] Execute Many - Request 12:17:06
[Start] DB Commit 12:17:08
[Stop program] 12:17:08
```